# React functional component won't display

Tags: reactjs, render

I've started to learn React lately and today to just memorize what i've learnt i decided to create a react component that contains a simple heading tag but i can't figure out why it won't be displayed in the browser here's my code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

    </div>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="include-component.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my react component which resides in file named include-component.js :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function IncludeComponent() {
    return(
            <TestComponent name="Hello Wolrd"/>
    );
}

function TestComponent(props) {
    return(
     <h1>{props.name}</h1>
    );
}
const app= document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<IncludeComponent/>,app);
```

can someone tell me why my component won't render ?

Comment: Can u put the relevant into a CodeSandbox. ?

Comment: i don't know how to do it can you show me how please?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new open this and update with your current code and share the URL in the question detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a confusing mixture of non-compiled code and compiled code. Did you checked your console? You surely have errors guiding you...

This is for when you don't have a compiler and React and ReactDOM will be available globally:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

I don't recommend you try this approach. It is sub optimal and none of the resources you will see online are using it.

Then you do this:

```
<script src="include-component.js"></script>
```

This will already cause an exception since you're using `import` statements inside this JS file, but you haven't said that it `type="module"`. Normal JS files can't use import statements.

Finally you can't import React and ReactDOM like that anyway, since you imported the browser versions which just have global variables.

Instead just start a project with [Create React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html):

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
yarn start
```

And start experimenting in that instead.

For completeness you would need to transform with babel:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      function IncludeComponent() {
        return(
          <TestComponent name="Hello Wolrd"/>
        );
      }

      function TestComponent(props) {
        return(
          <h1>{props.name}</h1>
        );
      }
      const container = document.getElementById('app');
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(app);
      root.render(<IncludeComponent/>);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i removed the import statement and now in the console it cought this error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: That's because the browser doesn't understand JSX, you need to transform it with babel. Again nobody develops like this, it is extremely unperformant and a  suboptimal dev experience, you shouldn't actually deploy it to a website. For completeness I updated with an example, I can't link to another JS file so I put it inline. But like I said you should just use Create React App.

Comment: yeah i took your advice and i'm using: npx create-react-app
thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

You must import the test component!!

```
import TestComponent from './TestComponent';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TestComponent name='hello world' />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i wrote them in the same file so i don't need to import it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).